# Excel change active cell color if within defined range

Tags: excel, colors, vba

I am new to VBA. In Excel, I have a defined range called "efficient"  which is B2:B10. When a user clicks a cell within that range, I want the cell outline to change red.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    Worksheets("LookupLists").Range.Value = ActiveCell.Address
End Sub
```

Comment: what do you mean by "cell outline" ? do you mean the borders ?

Comment: Yes, the border of the cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this in the LookupLists code section (which you're presumably doing already):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal target As Range)

  Dim rng As Range
  Set rng = Worksheets("LookupLists").Range("Efficient")

  If Intersect(target, rng) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

  Application.EnableEvents = False
  target.BorderAround ColorIndex:=3
  Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

This will change the border of a cell that is 'clicked' on (ie selected). Note that this will also draw a border around a group of selected cells in that range (ie click, hold and drag mouse) and will also color the cell if you move through the range using arrow keys  - which might not be entirely what you're after.

**EDIT**

To remove the border if you click elsewhere you can do try this instead:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal target As Range)

  Dim rng As Range
  Set rng = Worksheets("LookupLists").Range("Efficient")

  Application.EnableEvents = False
  If Intersect(target, rng) Is Nothing Then
    rng.Borders.Color = xlNone
  Else
    target.BorderAround ColorIndex:=3
  End If
  Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

But this will remove the borders for each selection change.  Also it's effect won't be really noticeable unless you move up the column.

Comment: Thanks Amorpheuses. This changes the color, but when I click off of the cell, it remains red.  Can it switch back to black when not active?